# Enable ZipArchive on localhost

Tags: php, localhost, php-ziparchive

I need to enable ZipArchive php class on my `localhost`, How can I enable it !?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? You need: PHP 5 >= 5.2.0 and PECL zip >= 1.1.0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

add `extension=zip.so` to your `php.ini` if you already have it installed (not sure what OS you're on)

Linux: `pecl install zip`

Restart the web server once php.ini is edited.

Comment: Using Windows 7 64bit, Also add extension=php_zip.dll; but still got the following error : 
Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in E:\AppServ\www\bazaar\admin\lib\ApkArchive.php on line 10

Comment: Then you need to download it from the pear website.  Here is exactly what you need: http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php

Comment: I copy php_zip.dll; to my root folder and ext folder but still got that error !!! Any ideas ?

Comment: you changed it to: extension=php_zip.dll right? And then restarted the web server (apache service)

Comment: That should do it.  Whats your error?

Comment: actually I changed it to extension=php_zip.dll;

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in E:\AppServ\www\test\lib\ApkArchive.php on line 10

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16832/discussion-between-isun-and-wes)

Comment: @iSun, so chat page not found, could you tell how you enabled the ZipArchive?

Comment: @BraveS By helping the above post.

Comment: @iSun, :"let us continue this discussion in chat – iSun" <- page not found
Or if you mean not a comment but a post - unfortunately it didn't work to me too ((

Comment: @BraveS It was a session between me and wesside, you can't check that page either!