# ZipArchive library is not enabled

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

When i am using PHPEXCEL in my code, ZipArchive library is not enabled is wont let me to run the code. How can I solve the issues?

Any one there?
please help me. I am tired of searching for it.

Comment: For PHP 7. Try this command to install and enable zip archive extension,   sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this​ post, may be helpful to you.
[Enable ZipArchive on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477837/enable-ziparchive-on-localhost)

Check your PHP version, for 7 might be different.